# Spark : default value for Encoder

Tags: apache-spark

Is there a way to choose default value for an encoder, if the field is not present in the parquet to be read ?

```
   public static final Encoder<ParquetModel> encoder = Encoders.bean(ParquetModel.class);
```

For example there is a field `Name` in my `ParquetModel`, but it's not in the schema of the parquet. Is there a way to specify the default value ?

Answer (score 0):

Spark, when reading Parquet files, uses `null` if no value is present for a column.

> When reading Parquet files, all columns are automatically converted to be nullable for compatibility reasons.([1](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html))

If you need a default value to be read other than `null`, you will have to read the data as a `DataFrame`, and transform it to fit the schema of your class (`ParquetModel`, in this case).

```
val dataset = spark.read.parquet("/usr/test.parquet").withColumn("Name", lit("John Doe")).as[ParquetModel]
```